# Acer aspire V5-171-6422 dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

My laptop has come with WIN8 and secure booting through UEFI (this is very new bootloader for me) I want to natively boot Ubuntu like using BIOS. Can anyone suggest me a way for this? I have read Ubuntu using intermediate signed bootloader and then switch to unsigned bootloader and kernel. I dont believe in security stories from microsoft on my laptop, and want to use it my way. Do share with me any of the pointers you may have

PS: I am happily using Ubuntu 11.04 (on desktop, laptop and VM) as I don't like forced unity in latest Ubuntu versions. But I doubt about driver support in that version for laptop in discussion. So I can change my mindset for booting natively with UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the 1st paragraph of the Ubuntu Community Documentation about UEFI:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

There is another step-by-step guide [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) that helped a lot of people (if the "likes" means that it helped).